# VBA - create a loop from data filtered

Tags: excel, vba

I need help to create automatically accounts entry.

I have 2 sheets:

- “DETAIL MAG” : in which are society IDs (as “FR240”, “FR520”,"FR020", etc…). Each one has amounts and VAT. I need all 3 (society ID, amount and VAT) to construct my account entry.
  [image]
- “IML”: where will be create accounts entry. It will have this schema bellow
  [image]

I wrote a code for **one** society ID ("FR520") and I would like **to apply it for all of them**. However, each month the ID society may change, or a new one can be add.

**What will change is where is insert "FR520" . The sum, the color, other values, etc... won't change.**
So I think a **loop** would be a solution but I don‘t know how to process.

Here a part of my code :

```
Sub Iml_FR520()
    
    'Déclaration des variables
    Dim FR520 As Range
    Dim SUM_FR520 As Double
    Dim DernLigne As Double
    
    DernLigne = Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'last row
    Set FR520 = Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'setting whole range of data
    Sheets("DETAIL MAG").AutoFilterMode = False 'turning off all filters
    FR520.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="FR520" 'filtering data
    SUM_FR520 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Range("R1:R" & DernLigne).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) 'summing filtered data
    
    Sheets("IML").Select
    
    ' Variable pour trouver la dernière ligne
     DernLigne = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    ' Insérer valeur FR520 en A
    Range("A" & DernLigne).Value = "FR520"
    Range("A" & DernLigne).Interior.Color = 65535
    
       
    ' Insérer Montant HT en G
    Range("G" & DernLigne).Value = SUM_FR520
    Range("G" & DernLigne).Interior.Color = 65535
    
    ' Insérér valeur AQ SOLDE en I
    Range("I" & DernLigne).Value = "AQ SOLDE"
    Range("I" & DernLigne).Interior.Color = 65535
    
End Sub

Sub Iml_FR520_TVA()

    Dim FR520 As Range
    Dim SUM_FR520 As Double
    Dim DernLigne1 As Double
    
    DernLigne1 = Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'last row
    Set FR520 = Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'setting whole range of data
    Sheets("DETAIL MAG").AutoFilterMode = False 'turning off all filters
    FR520.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="FR520" 'filtering data
    SUM_FR520 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("DETAIL MAG").Range("S1:S" & DernLigne1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) 'summing filtered data
    
    ' Variable pour trouver la dernière ligne
    Dim DernLigne As Double
    DernLigne = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 

    ' Insérer Montant TVA en G
    Range("G" & DernLigne).Value = SUM_FR520
    
    ' Insérér valeur TVA FIDELITE 20% en I
    Range("I" & DernLigne).Value = "TVA FIDELITE 20 %"
    
     
    ' Insérer Montant HT en P
    Range("P" & DernLigne).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C[-9]"
    
    ' Insérer Montant HT en Q
    Range("Q" & DernLigne).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a list of unique values from column L (FR240, FR520, FR020 etc) using a [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/dictionary-object) and then cycle through them using a `For Each ID In dictionary.keys` loop. Note row counters are integer so declare them as `Long` rather than `Double`.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Iml()

    Dim wsDetail As Worksheet, wsIML As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, DernLigne As Long, fn
    Dim rngR As Range, rngS As Range, rngFilter As Range
    Set fn = Application.WorksheetFunction
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsDetail = .Sheets("DETAIL MAG")
        Set wsIML = .Sheets("IML")
    End With
    
    Dim dictID As Object, ID, ar
    Set dictID = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With wsDetail
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        
        DernLigne = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngR = .Range("R2:R" & DernLigne) ' or should this be Q ?
        Set rngS = .Range("S2:S" & DernLigne)
        Set rngFilter = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        
        ' unique values FR240, FR520, FR020
        For i = 2 To DernLigne
            ID = Trim(.Cells(i, "L"))
            If Len(ID) > 0 Then
                dictID(ID) = i
            End If
        Next
    End With
        
    With wsIML
        DernLigne = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        ' loop through each ID in turn
        For Each ID In dictID.keys
            rngFilter.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=CStr(ID) 'col L
            .Cells(DernLigne, "A") = CStr(ID) ' Insérer valeur FR520 en A
            .Cells(DernLigne, "A").Interior.Color = vbYellow
            'Insérer Montant HT en G
            .Cells(DernLigne, "G") = fn.Sum(rngR.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
            .Cells(DernLigne, "G").Interior.Color = vbYellow
            .Cells(DernLigne, "I") = "AQ SOLDE"
            .Cells(DernLigne, "I").Interior.Color = vbYellow
            DernLigne = DernLigne + 1
            
            ' Insérér valeur TVA FIDELITE 20% en I
            .Cells(DernLigne, "A") = CStr(ID)
            .Cells(DernLigne, "G") = fn.Sum(rngS.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
            .Cells(DernLigne, "I").Value = "TVA FIDELITE 20 %"
            
            ' Insérer Montant HT en P
            .Cells(DernLigne, "P").FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C[-9]"
    
            ' Insérer Montant HT en Q
            .Cells(DernLigne, "Q").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
            DernLigne = DernLigne + 1
        Next
            
    End With
    wsDetail.AutoFilterMode = False
    MsgBox "Complet " & vbLf & Join(dictID.keys, vbLf), vbInformation
    
End Sub
```